# Getting branch from git

Tags: git

let's say I want to get [this branch](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.2.27) the same way I get the [latest one](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/), using `git clone git://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the branch tag to the clone process.

`git clone -b rpi-3.2.27 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git`